# Generating Combinations Based on Conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, combinatorics

I'm trying to write an algorithm that generates a list of an *a* size of lists where the **union** of any *b* amount of lists contains the set of numbers that appear in all lists. Also, no b - 1 amount of lists should contain the set of numbers that appear in all lists...

*a* can be between 1-9 and *b* can be between 0-9.

Example:

a = 3

b = 2

answer = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]]

I need three lists where the **union** of any 2 lists contains [0,1,2].

What  I've done so far is write two functions, one checks whether a list of lists meets the criteria and returns a Boolean, the other generates combnations until the criteria is met (very inefficient, only works when b < 3).

```
from itertools import combinations

# Checks if an answer is successful
def check(answer, b):
    # get set of total keys
    answer_set = []
    answer_set.extend([i for l in answer for i in l])

    answer_set = set(answer_set)

    # Check if all combinations of b size hold
    for target in combinations(answer, b):
        test = set([i for l in target for i in l])
        if not answer_set.issubset(test):
            return False

    # Check if it doesn't hold for b - 1
    for fail in combinations(answer, b - 1):
        test = set([i for l in fail for i in l])
        if answer_set.issubset(test):
            return False

    # Return True if all tests were passed
    return True

#  Brute force all combinations
def brute(a, b, answer=1):

    # Establish set of numbers to try
    test_set = set(range(answer))

    # Test if set of numbers contains a passing answer
    for attempt in range(10):
        test_set.add(len(test_set))
        set_combo = combinations(test_set, attempt)

        for combo in combinations(set_combo, a):
            if check(combo, b):
                return combo

    return brute(a, b, answer + 1)
```

If I typed everything in correctly, we should have code that answers my example above (albeit I believe it returns a tuple of tuples, but that isn't as important for now). Note: there are special cases that my brute force doesn't solve, like when a == b.

Obviously, the brute force isn't going to work on larger sized because the amount of possible combinations becomes insane to deal with. I need a new approach...

My thoughts moving forward would be to identify a special relationship between a and b, such that I can calculate the number of possible combinations whose union is the set of numbers which appear in all sets. Any information I can glean from a and b to get the size of lists and the possible number values of each item would be my next guess.

Anyway, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Union, not intersection.

Comment: You talking about `permutations` not `combinations`[Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values)

Comment: Are you talking about intersection or union? Part '... where the intersection of any 2 lists contains [0,1,2]' doesn't add up. Is your problem maybe similar to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475811/subset-and-set-cover).

Comment: @dsgdfg I don't think permutations is correct because I am not concerned with order of elements. For my purposes, [1,2] and [2,1] are the same list. However, the algorithm linked might be helpful in creating an algorithm that doesn't yield all possible combinations, but just the combinations I am concerned with.

Comment: @Ante Ooops, yes I mean union. I edited the post to reflect that.

Also, the question you linked too is essentially the same problem I'm dealing with so we might want to close this up and just link to that.

Comment: I think this still needs to be edited _"... the number of possible combinations whose intersection is the set of numbers which appear in all sets"_

Comment: What would the answer be if `b` is `0`. And if `b > a`?

Comment: @MarcosModenesi I believe that is either an empty list or a list of empty lists.